# Windows 8.1 app on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm creating a windows 8 app and i need to update it to windows 8.1.

I have a tablet PC which i don't want to install windows 8.1. Is it possible to run an app for windows 8.1 on windows 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Btw, the Windows 8 app will run just fine on Windows 8.1 also.  But if you want to update your app for Windows 8.1, then you can create it specifically for Windows 8.1.  Then the Windows 8 machines will get the Windows 8 version and Windows 8.1 machines will get the Windows 8.1 version.